# Can I use PHP print as Input Field's default Value?

Tags: php

I have placed a php code for getting current page URL and now I can get current page URL by writing this code

```
<?php print(selfURL()); ?>
```

Now, I want to know how can I write this code as the default value of Input field?
Actually I want the Input field to automatically filled up with the current page URL.

When I use `<?php print(selfURL()); ?>` as `value="<?php print(selfURL()); ?>"` it simple shows a text and don't display current url. But when I paste it in other place then its working fine.

Any suggestions?

UpDATE:

Guys, this is the full code of the page, may be it helps!

```
<?php
function selfURL() { $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : ""; $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s; $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]); return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; } function strleft($s1, $s2) { return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2)); }
?>
<?php 
// Start YOURLS engine
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/load-yourls.php' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YOURLS Public Interface Sample</title>
<style>
body {
    background:#E3F3FF;
    color:#595441;
    font:16px/30px verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
a, a:visited {color:#2A85B3}
h1 {text-align:center; color:#2A85B3}
h2 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #2A85B3;
    color:#2A85B3;
    margin-left:-10px;
    padding-left:25px;
    width:80%;
}
#container {
    width: 780px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #2A85B3;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
}
#footer {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#footer p {
    padding:5px;
    background:white;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:750px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #2A85B3;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:35px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:35px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
}
#footer p a {
    background:#fff url(http://yourls.org/images/favicon.gif) 2px center no-repeat;
    padding-left:20px;
}
div#copybox { width:600px; height:auto;}
div#sharebox {height:auto; width:600px; margin-top:20px;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo YOURLS_SITE; ?>/css/share.css?v=<?php echo YOURLS_VERSION; ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="<?php echo YOURLS_SITE; ?>/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo YOURLS_SITE; ?>/js/ZeroClipboard.js?v=<?php echo YOURLS_VERSION; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( '<?php echo YOURLS_SITE; ?>/js/ZeroClipboard.swf' );</script>
<script src="<?php echo YOURLS_SITE; ?>/js/share.js?v=<?php echo YOURLS_VERSION; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>YOURLS: Your Own URL Shortener</h1>

<div id="container">

    <?php

    // Part to be executed if FORM has been submitted
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['url']) ) {

        $url     = yourls_sanitize_url( $_REQUEST['url'] );

        $return  = yourls_add_new_link( $url );

        $shorturl = isset( $return['shorturl'] ) ? $return['shorturl'] : '';


        echo <<<RESULT
        <h2>URL has been shortened</h2>
        <p>Original URL: <code><a href="$url">$url</a></code></p>
        <p>Short URL: <code><a href="$shorturl">$shorturl</a></code></p>

RESULT;



    // Part to be executed when no form has been submitted
    } else {

        $site = YOURLS_SITE;

        echo <<<HTML
        <h2>Enter a new URL to shorten</h2>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <p><label>URL: <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo selfURL(); ?>" size="70" /></label></p>
        <p><label>Optional custom keyword: $site/<input type="text" name="keyword" size="8" /></label></p>
        <p><label>Optional title: <input type="text" name="title" size="57" /></label></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Shorten" /></p>
        </form> 
HTML;

    }

    ?>


</div>





<?php print(selfURL()); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "When I use <?php print(selfURL()); ?> as value="<?php print(selfURL()); ?>" it simple shows a text and don't display current url"? Little confusing

Comment: Sorry about that, I want to have Current Page URL as the default value of input field. So I have added that code.
You can check the full page code above.

Comment: @Taimoor: Explain what text you get. Generally URL is a string if you print that string in href attribute of anchor tag that will be consider to navigate. If you print url string in textbox as a value, you get as a text only. you cann't navigate by using any of user action. Clear up, what you exactly want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the solution :

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

**Tested Code is as below**

```
<input type="text" name="" id="" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"/>
```

**your code edit**

```
$var = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
OR
$var = selfURL();

<p><label>URL: <input type="text" name="url" value="$var" size="70" /></label></p>
```

You are adding php inside her-doc syntax and that's the error

Comment: Getting this error with this code:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: may be you should try print instead of echo

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code must be problem in your declaration what code you have tried...are u adding it in php blocks.? because this error occur if you have problem in escaping single or double quotes.

Comment: I have updated question, with the complete code of page, you can check that.

Comment: What can I do now? Can you find a solution for this please?

Comment: Yes, this code update is working but its not showing TLD, I mean its just adding /y/index.php and not www.example.com

Comment: so you can replace $var with your selfURL() function...do it i am sure it will work.

Comment: great don't forget to accept this answer and +1...lol...welcome dude always here to help everyone if i can

Comment: Hah! Thank you! Yes, accepted but I think I'm not allowed to +1.. :p

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<input name="textVal" type="text" val=<?php echo selfURL(); ?> />
```

Comment: As user has updated his question, you can either change your answer or removed the same so it won't misguide the other SO fellows :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below.

**Method 1**

```
 <input name="myinput" type = "text" value = "<?php print(selfURL()); ?>" />
```

**Method 2**

```
<input name="myinput" type = "text" value = "<?php echo selfURL(); ?>" />
```

Answer after question has been updated

```
<input type="text" name="" id="" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"/>
```

Comment: did you try the both methods ? did you check whether function returns a string ?

Comment: Yes I have checked both of them... both of them just simple appear as text and don't display current page url.

Comment: As user has updated his question, you can either change your answer or removed the same so it won't misguide the other SO fellows :)